# Nested conditional throwing an error

Tags: r, nested

I have a column of integers from three digits to five digits.  I want to output a column of six characters (`czCode`) with the appropriate number of leading zeros depending on the input integer.

```
a <- seq(100, 50000, 1)
df1 <- data.frame(a)
View(df1)

myZero <- '0'
dblZero <- '00'
triZero <- '000'

a <- mutate(a, czCode = as.character(a))

df1$a <- ifelse(df1$a < 1000, paste(triZero, df1$czCode, sep = ""),
                ifelse(df1$a >= 1000 & df1$a < 10000, paste(dblZero, df1$czCode, sep = ""),
                ifelse(df1$a >= 10000, paste(myZero, df1$a, sep = "")),
                ))
```

So 100 would output as "000100"

and 1000 would output as "001000"

and 10000 would output as "010000"

But I keep getting the following error:

> Error in ifelse(df1$a >= 1000 & df1$a < 10000, paste(dblZero, df1$czCode,  :
>       unused argument ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [suchait explained the reason for the encountered error message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47702675/3817004), there is a better way to convert a number to character with leading zeros:

```
sprintf("%06i", 10^(2:4))
```

> ```
> [1] "000100" "001000" "010000"
> ```

The conversion specification `%06i` tells `sprintf()` to convert integer and "integerish" values using a field width of 6 characters and to pad to field width with leading zeros.

By the way, `paste0(x, y)` is a short-cut for `paste(x, y, sep = "")`.

Comment: Thank you. This is a great function I didn't even know existed... will save me lots of time in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing last argument of last if-else. I tried something like this, it worked for me:-

```
df1$a <- ifelse(df1$a < 1000, paste(triZero, df1$czCode, sep = ""),
            ifelse(df1$a >= 1000 & df1$a < 10000, paste(dblZero, df1$czCode, sep = ""),
                   ifelse(df1$a >= 10000, paste(myZero, df1$a, sep = ""), F)
              ))
```

Comment: This does not produce my desired output.

Comment: I have just used your if-else to make it work. Because you were encountering an error. I gave you a solution to what was wrong with that statement.